# Jenkins integration with Artifactory and promotion

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am new to Artifactory and would like to know the below

1. Suppose Jenkins produces the build artifacts( binary or jar) and is deployed to Artifactory repo and at the same time deployed to Dev environment. How do I move the same artifacts to Test environment? Do I need a new Jenkins job? or it can be moved from Artifactory itself ? how
2. If i build a project 10 times than 10 artifacts will be produces and latest one can be deployed to DEV env. How do I roll back to earlier version?

Can someone explain how does it works jenkins-artifactory

-Thanks

Comment: You should start by reading the [Artifactory Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) documentation

Comment: Are you using a Jenkinsfile checked into your repository? If so you can script it all the way you want it.